# solve by intuition or counting

Tags: probability

Say there are 1000 people, and you arbitrarily choose 50 of them. What's the probability you choose the "first" person?

To solve this type of problem, I always count: $$\frac{1 * \binom{999}{49}}{\binom{1000}{50}}$$

But when I asked my friend, he immediately said 50/1000 without doing a counting argument. How does someone know the answer w/o doing the counting because otherwise I just don't know how to do it. My friend just said "it just is" but that's obviously a useless answer haha.

Comment: Let $X_1$ be the probability that the first person is chosen.  Since the number of times the first person is chosen is either $0$ or $1$, $X_1$ is also the expected number of times the first person is chosen (in any single trial).  By symmetry and linearity of expectation, $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{1000} = 50$, and the result obtains.

Answer (score 2):

Make your choices in the other order.  First arbitrarily (and with equal probability) choose a subset of $50$ people.  What is the probability that a person selected randomly and uniformly from within your group of $1000$ is within that subset?  Seems pretty clear that probability is $50$ hits out of a universe of $1000$.

Answer (score 2):

### Method 1 - The obvious method

Your idea of a "first person" is similar to marking out one person, so I'll call that person A.

Now the chance that A won't be chosen will be given as follows:

In the group of 1000 people, there are 999 ways to choose someone else. Hence, probability from this step will be $\frac{999}{1000}$.

In the remaining group of 999 people, there are 998 ways to choose someone else. Hence probability from this step will be $\frac{998}{999}$.

In the remaining group of 998 people, there are 997 ways to choose someone else. Hence probability from this step will be $\frac{997}{998}$.

...

In the remaining group of 951 people, there are 950 ways to choose someone else. Hence probability from this step will be $\frac{950}{951}$.

This means that the chance that A won't be chosen is $\frac{999}{1000}\cdot\frac{998}{999}\cdot\frac{997}{998}\cdot ...\cdot\frac{950}{1000} = \frac{950}{1000}$.

Hence the chance that A will be chosen is $1-\frac{950}{1000}=\frac{50}{1000}$.

### Method 2 - A logical method

Probability-wise, there is nothing distinguishing A from any other person. Hence, every person has an equal probability of being chosen.

Hence, the chance that, in those 50 people,  A will be a member, would be $\frac{50}{1000}$.